# Antlr4: line 1:14 extraneous input 'w' expecting {<EOF>, ';', ' '}

Tags: antlr4

I try to write a Grammar which checks if the following data (a csv-file) is valid:

```
w;w;w;s;s;s;s
w;s;w;w;w;w;w
w;s;w;w;w;w;w
w;s;w;s;s;s;w
w;s;w;w;w;w;w
w;s;w;w;w;w;w
w;w;s;s;w;w;w



* Define a grammar Battlefield
 */
grammar Battlefield;
file : row* EOF;
row : value (Separator value)* (LineFeed |EOF) ;
value : SimpleValue ;
Separator : ';' ;

// line feed
LineFeed : '\n';

// w or s is allowed
SimpleValue : ('s'|'w'|'\n')+ ;

WS : [ \t\r]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs
```

When running the grammar I get the following error code:

```
line 1:14 extraneous input 'w' expecting {<EOF>, ';', '
'}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SimpleValue` rule will always consume a trailing `\n`, so no `LineFeed` token will ever be generated. Just remove the `\n` alt from the `SimpleValue` rule.

Comment: After I removed \n I get the message: 'line 7:13 missing SimpleValue at '<EOF>''